# Use infer_objects() while Looping Through List of DFs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is it possible to utilize *.infer_objects()* method of a Pandas' dataframe while looping through a list of DFs?

Sample Loop:

```
frame_list = [frame01, frame02]
for index, item in enumerate(frame_list):
  item.columns.names = ['columnNames_list']
  # item = item.infer_objects() # fails
  # frame_list[index] = item.infer_objects() # fails
  # item = frame_list[index].infer_objects() # fails
```

When I loop through the DF list, I can manipulate the *.columns.names* and *.index.names* attributes, for instance, but I cannot seem to infer the data types using *.infer_objects()* in the loop.  To be clear, it fails to change any of the data types.  In this case, all the fields remain 'object' data types, including those that become 'float64' or 'int' when applying *.infer_objects()* to the DFs individually.

I source my data from *.xls sheets with a number of empty rows before the data starts.  I could manually remove those rows, of course, but then I have a manual step in my work flow.

Most of the SO topics I found deal with changing or updating or modifying a particular column (Series) of a DF inside a for loop, which does not apply here.  A few noted that we should all avoid modifying the components of a list while looping through it by referencing by index and by making a copy of the DF.  Great advice, but I've tried various combinations of assignments withing the loop, etc. without any luck.

Sample Data:

> "pd.DataFrame({'Unnamed: 0': pd.Series([nan, nan, nan, nan,
>   'portName', 'port01', 'port01', 'port01', 'port01', 'port01',
>   'port02', 'port02', 'port02', 'port02',
>   'port02'],dtype='object',index=pd.RangeIndex(start=0, stop=15,
>   step=1)), 'Unnamed: 1': pd.Series([nan, nan, nan, nan, 'secID',
>   '10000A00', '10000A01', '10000A02', '10000A03', '10000A04',
>   '10000A05', '10000A06', '10000A07', '10000A08',
>   '10000A09'],dtype='object',index=pd.RangeIndex(start=0, stop=15,
>   step=1)), 'Unnamed: 2': pd.Series([nan, nan, nan, nan, 'cpn', 5.25,
>   6.25, 6.25, 7.25, 6.25, 6.25, 7.25, 8.25, 7.25, 6.25],dtype='object',index=pd.RangeIndex(start=0, stop=15, step=1)), 'Unnamed: 3': pd.Series([nan, nan, nan, nan, 'matDt',
>   datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 15, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2038, 7, 1, 0,
>   0), datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2045, 1,
>   16, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2029, 9, 25, 0, 0),
>   datetime.datetime(2033, 7, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2027, 8, 1, 0,
>   0), datetime.datetime(2041, 10, 15, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2024, 10,
>   1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2038, 6, 15, 0,
>   0)],dtype='object',index=pd.RangeIndex(start=0, stop=15, step=1)),
>   'Unnamed: 4': pd.Series([nan, nan, nan, nan, 'avgLife', 0.04, 7.69,
>   0.25, 3.76, 1.18, 8.23, 0.09, 8.29, 1.25, 6.96],dtype='object',index=pd.RangeIndex(start=0, stop=15, step=1)), 'Unnamed: 5': pd.Series([nan, nan, nan, nan, 'rtgNAIC', 2, 1, 1, 1, 1,
>   1, 1, 1, 1, 1],dtype='object',index=pd.RangeIndex(start=0, stop=15,
>   step=1)), 'Unnamed: 6': pd.Series([nan, nan, nan, nan, 'bookValue',
>   6620257.15, 5000000, 4999338.08, 4807411.33, 4753268.3, 2485506.77, 2300666.34, 2269412.57, 2250000, 2235763.43],dtype='object',index=pd.RangeIndex(start=0, stop=15, step=1))}, index=pd.RangeIndex(start=0, stop=15, step=1))"

Comment: How exactly does it fail?

Comment: It fails to change any of the data types.  In this case, all the fields remain 'object' data types, including those that become 'float64' or 'int' when applying *.infer_objects()* to the DFs individually.